# Passing multiple variable in url

Tags: php

Hello there I have a page that pass 2 variable in url and use switch to include different php page.

here's my code to my index.php(for template)

```
<a href="?p=about">about </a> | <a href="?p=gallery">gallery</a>

<?php
$x=isset($_GET['p'])?$_GET['p']:"";
switch($x)
{
 case"about":include("about.php");break;
 case"gallery":include("gallery.php");break;
 default:include("home.php");
}
?>
```

a code to my gallery.php

```
<a href="?p=gallery&albumID=1">ALBUM 1</a> | <a href="?p=gallery&albumID=2">ALBUM 2</a>

<?php
$y=isset($_GET['p'])?$_GET['p']:"";
switch($y)
{
 case 1:include("album1.php");break;
 case 2:include("album2.php");break;
}
?>
```

and code of my album1.php

```
<img src="img1.png"><img src="img2.png"><img src="img3.png">
```

---

my problem is when I open the link http://sample.com/?p=gallery&albumID=1
it loads two php file. and it looks like this

about | gallery
ALBUM 1 | ALBUM 2
Image 1 Image 2 Image 3

I want to remove the inlcuded php file(gallery.php) without changing the link
http://sample.com/?p=gallery&albumID=1

is any possible way to remove that? or not to include when the link loaded

Comment: Just to clarify, you dont want to show link to page that is currently loaded or it is something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no (trivial) way to remove the included file after it's been included.

But why don't you just include your navigation links when no album is included? Like this (gallery.php):

```
<?php
$y=isset($_GET['albumID'])?$_GET['albumID']:"";
switch($y)
{
 case 1:include("album1.php");break;
 case 2:include("album2.php");break;
 default: echo '<a href="?p=gallery&albumID=1">ALBUM 1</a> | <a href="?p=gallery&albumID=2">ALBUM 2</a>'; break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<a href="?p=gallery&albumID=1">ALBUM 1</a> | <a href="?p=gallery&albumID=2">ALBUM 2</a>

<?php
$x=isset($_GET['p'])?$_GET['p']:"";
$y=isset($_GET['albumID'])?$_GET['albumID']:"";
if ($y != "" && $x != "" && $x == "gallery")
{
switch($y)
{
 case 1:include("album1.php");break;
 case 2:include("album2.php");break;
}
} else {
switch($x)
{
 case"about":include("about.php");break;
 case"gallery":include("gallery.php");break;
 default:include("home.php");
}

}

?>
```